# date String "08th August 2017" to date conversion in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL, I have a column value like this `08th August 2017`.

I want to convert it into a date like `8-8-2017`. I have tried MySQL `date_formate()` function, `STR_TO_DATE()` function but it return a null value.

How can do this task ?

Comment: Can we see your attempt with the STR_TO_DATE() function?

Comment: Small Note: You should not have a date saved on your database in that format. Always use DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP fields for storing dates. Then you wont have this probelm

Comment: @RiggsFolly True - but to be fair, we don't know that this is a SELECT

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('08th August 2017', '%D %M %Y')` works fine for me

Comment: Nice one - spoilsport ;-)

Comment: And @PriyaSetiawan actually goes all the way and produces the actual output requested by the OP

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, actually, we don't know that.

Comment: I also assumed that the OP was just mistyping the 'standard' `DATE` format but then again who knows

Comment: @Strawberry Well I think taht is what this bit of the question says _I want to convert it into a date like "8-8-2017"_ would you not agree??

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Well, the OP said 'date' not 'string' so it would be in favor of my answer ;)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is that August 8th, or 8th August?

Comment: @Strawberry Ah the eternal date issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `%D %M %Y` format for `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datefield,'%D %M %Y')
FROM yourtable
```

Input

```
08th August 2017
```

Output

```
2017-08-08
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/701e66/5/0

Answer (score 1):

First convert your date string into a DATETIME value and then use that in a `DATE_FORMAT()` to get the date into whatever format you want

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('08th August 2017', '%D %M %Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') AS 
test;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code in mysql.

**I am just giving example how to use.**

```
select STR_TO_DATE("08th August 2017", "%d %m %y") from demo
```

**where demo is the demo table.**